# EBS Snapshot to S3 with file structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I know its possible to copy EBS snapshots to a viewable S3 path.  However, will it copy in such a way that I can browse the directory structure of the snapshot as if it was actually mounted?

I have an server with about 70gigs of images/photos..etc that I want to put on CloudFront/S3 but was hoping not to have to copy via S3cmd or scripts..etc

Comment: I'm going to use s3fs to mount S3 and transfer my assets that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is not a block device, therefore you do not have a filesystem there. It is an object storage and the reason that you see files and folders through the AWS web console is because the console represents it that way.

To achieve what you describe, you might want to look at [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) (FUSE based). It creates a pseudo-drive for you to work with. Mind you, the overhead is substantial and as such the performance is not even close to a network shared folder.

Comment: Alternately, look into s3sync.net or similar tools. They are slightly simpler to setup, and *much* easier to debug. (i.e. you can see real error messages instead of being hidden deep in the FS layer.)